# Compiling OpenCV inside a conda virtual environment

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, osx-yosemite, opencv3.0, conda

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.0.0 inside of a virtual environment I have created using `conda`.

I have downloaded the zip file for OpenCV 3.0.0, unzipped it, and created an empty directory called `build` inside of the unzipped directory. Inside of build, I am trying to run

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
-D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print get_python_inc()") \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python) \
-D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()") ..
```

Along with several other variations of the `cmake` command described above, but I get a `dyld library not loaded error`.

What is the correct `cmake command` to install OpenCV inside my `conda` virtual environment?

Comment: You doesn't pass source directory to the `cmake`. And, probably, incorrectly pass variables. Try to get CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX hardcoded value, instead of being result of the script.

Comment: You are missing the flag `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY` pointing to the python dylib (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I followed to build opencv 3.0 on OS X:

```
# From opencv root:
mkdir build
cd build
PYTHON_VERS=python$(python -c "import sys; print '%s.%s' % (sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor)")
PYTHON_ROOT=$(python -c "import sys; print sys.prefix")

cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$PYTHON_ROOT/include/$PYTHON_VERS/ -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$PYTHON_ROOT/lib/lib${PYTHON_VERS}.dylib -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$PYTHON_ROOT/bin/python -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$PYTHON_ROOT/lib/$PYTHON_VERS/site-packages/ ..
make
sudo make install | grep cv2.so
cp /usr/local/lib/$PYTHON_VERS/site-packages/cv2.so $PYTHON_ROOT/lib/$PYTHON_VERS/site-packages/cv2.so # or wherever it installs it...
```

(For some reason it still ends up building the python bindings .so in the `/usr/local/lib` version of python so I had to copy it over, but there may be an additional flag you can use to prevent that)

Comment: will this work if I have installed python with anaconda?

Comment: Haven't tried, but in theory it should.  I did it with a macports build of Python-2.7 (with numpy and scipy pip installed previously)

Comment: ok, can you give more detail as to where it failed and what the error was? Did it successfully build but no python bindings?